# How to resolve the "java.lang.nullpointerexception null value in entry url=null " in Selenium(POM)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, xml-file

**1.TestCommands.java**

```
public class TestCommands {
public void click(By locator,WebDriver driver){
    try {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
        element.click();            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
public void type(By locator,WebDriver driver,String key){
    try {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys(key);          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
public void open(String url,WebDriver driver) {
    try {
        driver.get(url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

}

**2.LoginPage.java**

```
public class LoginPage extends TestCommands{
//web elements
public By userName(){
    return By.xpath("//input[@id='user-name']");
}
public By password(){
    return By.xpath("//input[@id='user-password']");
}
public By loginButton(){
    return By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='SIGN IN'])[1]/following::div[2]");
}

//Business functions
public void openApplication(String url,WebDriver driver){
    open(url,driver);
}
public void loginToApplication(WebDriver driver,String userName,String password){
    type(userName(),driver,userName);
    type(password(),driver,password);
    click(loginButton(),driver);
}
```

}

**3.TC_LoginToTest.java**

```
public class TC_LoginToTest {
WebDriver driver ;
String baseUrl;
LoginPage login = new LoginPage(); 

@Parameters("browser")
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(String browser) {

    if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } else if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();            
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}  
@DataProvider
public Object[][] tc001() {
    return new Object[][] {
            new Object[] {"nadee","12345678"},      
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider="tc001")
public void tc001(String userName , String password) {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    login.openApplication("https://test.com", driver);
    login.loginToApplication(driver, userName, password);
}
}
```

I have use the xml file as follows to send the browser type,

```
**4.xml file**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
<test name="Test">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <classes>
      <class name="Systemloginfunctionalities.TC_LoginToTest"/>
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

But I have received an error as follows in the TestNG ,
      java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null

Please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: How did you resolve it? Can you pls share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
@Test(dataProvider="tc001")
public void tc001(String userName , String password) {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    login.openApplication("https://test.com", driver);
    login.loginToApplication(driver, userName, password);
}
```

you have `driver.get(baseUrl);` that receives `baseUrl` which is null (you are not assigning a value for that string anywhere)

Comment: Thanks for your response.my test successfully passed,but i just wanted know whether I can print a success message for the try catch codes in the TestCommands.java to the console as well,can i have some advice from you?as i am new to the automation testing